# Forwarding requests to known suspicious site to an isolated server

Tags: network, malware, dns

I keep getting IPS alerts for suspicious DNS requests for a known host with malware. I can't find anything from the Windows DNS logs from the domain controllers because it just shows the source address as the one from the DNS server.

How do I forward all requests to ns.example.com to an isolated server to see which PC is making the requests?

Comment: Can you just set a record in your DNS server for that domain that points to a local server under your control?  Does the DNS server not have its own logs?